# Bootstrap shadow not displaying on nav.shadow

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar component made with vue.js. I am styling the app with bootstrap so I have included bootstrap in the main html file.

I have built the navbar component and added the styling that I want but when I add the shadow or shadow-lg class the shadow does not appear at all. I have tried increasing the z-index of the navbar but the shadow still does not show.

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-rounded shadow-lg" style="z-index: 100;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ logo_text }}</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" 
                        v-for="(item, index) in links"
                        :key="index"
                    >
                        <a :href="item.href" class="nav-link">{{ item.text }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Note that the class navbar-rounded is a custom class I added with the styling

```
.navbar-rounded {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

How would I get the shadow to display correctly?

Comment: When you inspect the relevant element in the developer tools does it appear to have the appropriate shadow CSS applied? If it does, try adding a `margin: 10px` to that element, just as a test. It might be that the shadow is being clipped by `overflow: hidden` on an ancestor and the margin will allow you to see the shadow if it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow has been applied properly. There is no issue on applying styles.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/dvzLsfjg/5/), where I converted `navbar` to a lighter version. There you can see shadow is applied. The reason is due to dark theme applied, you can't see a color seperation between `navbar` background color and it's shadow color.

Clarify this issue by applying `shadow`, `shadow-sm` and `shadow-lg` classes on `nav` element.

Hope this will help to fix your issue.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-rounded shadow" style="z-index: 100;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ logo_text }}</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" 
                        v-for="(item, index) in links"
                        :key="index"
                    >
                        <a :href="item.href" class="nav-link">{{ item.text }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Sorted as needed and gave me an idea too.

Comment: @SnipsYT Great. It's my pleasure. :)